# What is the right design pattern for custom template types in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's my situation: I've got a number of specialized object types in my application, and I'm following the standard convention for displaying them with custom templates in the `/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder, and editing them with templates in `/Shared/EditorTemplates`.  But I also want to be able to display a custom filter template for each type, so I'd like to add a `/Shared/FilterTemplates` folder, and implement my own `@Html.FilterFor` method, so that showing a Filter template is exactly like showing a Display or Editor template.

Does this seem like the best way to handle this situation, or is there a more correct/elegant way to do this in MVC?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's say you have an Id field.  The display template shows this in a label and the editor template shows it in a textbox.  The filter template would show a custom UI that would show, for instance, two textboxes, "From" and "To", to allow you to specify a range of Id values that you use to filter the rows, only getting rows where the Id is in that range.  Similarly for all the other fields and data types.  Or maybe a Name field would show a textbox and let you specify wildcards or a regex pattern so you can find rows where the name matches that pattern.

Comment: What wrong with your solution I think it a proper way to do it to write your custom template

Comment: I don't know that anything's wrong with it, but I wanted to know if it was perhaps a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always using EditorTemplates when data is sent back to server. I assume the user can submit the filter to the server to perform the actual filtering.

When creating filters I prefer to create a model for the filter like:

```
public class UserListFilterModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

The view for UserListFilterModel goes into EditorTemplates/UserListFilterModel.ascx.

And then add it as a property on my view model for the page.

```
public class MyPageViewModel
{
    public UserListFilterModel Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Then I add the filter model to the model for the page and displays it like this:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Filter)%>
```

You are probably wrapping the filter in a form to allow the user to submit the values so I think it belongs in EditorTemplates. The users is in fact editing the filter model.

(If you really want to separate them ing you could use the [UIHintAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.uihint.aspx) but I wouldn't)

Edit: I added some sample code.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me clarify what I needed to do.  You're right, it's not that there's a separate kind of template, it's that there's a separate kind of ViewModel, which in turn is either being displayed or edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how Templates work.  Templates do not make sense in the context you are describing.

Templates work on a *SINGLE* data item (although that data item can contain multiple data items, which in turn have their own templates).

The concept of a Filter is to control multiple data items, thus they do not map well to a template.

What you could do is create a DisplayTemplate for your collection class that adds filtering, thus no need to create a custom type of template.  Just use DisplayTemplates.